# Create a new dataframe by aggregating repeated origin and destination values by a separate count column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I am having trouble analysing origin-destination values in a pandas dataframe which contains origin/destination columns and a count column of the frequency of these. I want to transform this into a dataframe with the count of how many are leaving and entering:

Initial:

```
    Origin  Destination  Count

    A       B            7
    A       C            1
    B       A            1
    B       C            4
    C       A            3
    C       B            10
```

For example this simplified dataframe has 7 leaving from A to B and 1 from A to C so overall leaving place A would be 8, and entering place A would be 4 (B - A is 1, C - A is 3) etc. The new dataframe would look something like this.

Goal:

```
   Place   Entering  Leaving

   A       4         8
   B       17        5
   C       5         13
```

I have tried several techniques such as .groupby() but have not yet created my intended dataframe. How can I handle the repeated values in the origin/destination columns and assign them to a new dataframe with aggregated values of just the count of leaving and entering?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double `groupby` + [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
a = df.groupby('Destination')['Count'].sum()
b = df.groupby('Origin')['Count'].sum()

df = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1, keys=('Entering','Leaving')).rename_axis('Place').reset_index()
print (df)
  Place  Entering  Leaving
0     A         4        8
1     B        17        5
2     C         5       13
```

Comment: Dual groupby is always used to be my thing : )

Comment: @Bharath - Thanks.

Comment: Ah so groupby then **concat** is the way to go - thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

`pivot_table` then do `sum`

```
df=pd.pivot_table(df,index='Origin',columns='Destination',values='Count',aggfunc=sum)
pd.concat([df.sum(0),df.sum(1)],1)

Out[428]: 
      0     1
A   4.0   8.0
B  17.0   5.0
C   5.0  13.0
```